# How can i set up an unit testing system to test against a Web API 2?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my set up and dilema

We have created an ipad application that uses an HTML wrapper to display information to the user. It is a telerik App builder solution running an HTML 5 site with JS and connect to our web API side for fetching data.

The server side is a WEB API 2 running on a web project, no Katana, just a the same modified template from the SPA sample file.

The way the user authenticates on the IPAD is by issuing a /token request. In fact here is the 
actual fiddler traffic when the user request a token

```
POST http://development01/MobileAPITest/Token HTTP/1.1
Host: development01
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: */*
Origin: file://
Content-Length: 57
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Mobile/11D257 (391865488)

grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=pass1234
```

So. How can i set up a test system to test this at the http level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to test the Web Api itself?

You shouldn't have a need to test the controllers via HTTP protocol, the framework has been tested to work up until the point of giving your method a request object and a deserialized version of the incoming model.

Setup a test project for the site and test the controller functionality by directly issuing commands to the controller methods. This relieves you of the burden of having a HTTP client mixed with the testing.

If you necessary want to write tests that include calling the API via HTTP then I suggest you either use a HTTP client to call your API from the test project.

A good step-by-step unit testing tutorial for ASP.NET Web Api 2 can be found here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api

And for testing with routing:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: In the route of wanting to test using the HTTP client, how can it be achieved?

Comment: You can find a good step-by-step tutorial for Web Api 2 unit testing (Can also be applied to prior versions) here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: For testing with routing, see this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: And finally an external unit testing framework for all http interfaced rest APIs http://frisbyjs.com/